# Hematuria due to Nitric Oxide

Tags: human-biology, physiology, pharmacology, kidney, surgery

> Drug interactions between properly dosed NO and other medications are not expected, but side effects may include noisy breathing, **hematuria**, or possibly atelectasis. (pg.no:577; Goodman and Gilman Pharmacology 13e)

What is the basis for this hematuria?  Is it because of platelet inhibiting activity of Nitric Oxide?